# Azure Event Hub stard receiving events from specified time

Tags: event-handling, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

Is there any way to set up event hub that it is starts receiving events (from iot hub) from specified time ? Sometimes I nedd to do little changes in my code and I don't want to do again some actions on data that was send before I deploy my new event hub code. Maybe I should use something different to provide custom logic to my iot hub data, that allow me to do custom logic on received data without doing same code on data that I received beforce deploy my service ?

Comment: In addition to the answer of @Mikhail, you could use different consumergroups for different logic. each consumergroups can have its own initial offset and its own progress of the processing the data.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which API you use, but here are two options:

- If you are receiving the events directly with `EventHubReceiver`, there is a `CreateReceiver()` method overload which accepts `DateTime startingDateTimeUtc`, see [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubconsumergroup.createreceiver?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventHubConsumerGroup_CreateReceiver_System_String_System_DateTime_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_ReceiverOptions_)
- If you are using `EventProcessorHost`, you can specify the *initial* timestamp offset as part of `EventProcessorOptions.InitialOffsetProvider`, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventprocessoroptions.initialoffsetprovider?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_EventProcessorOptions_InitialOffsetProvider). I believe the existing checkpoints will override this value, so you'd have to clean up the checkpoints in blob storage while deploying a new version